# Cancellation in the exponential function

Tags: numerical-methods, computational-mathematics, floating-point

I have the following issue about numerical analysis:

[image]

Well, part a) is the one I did, in the following code in Octave

```
function val=miexp(x)
ep=10^(-15);
val=1.0; n=1; e0=0;
do
e0=val;
val+=(x)^(n)/factorial(n);
n++;
until(abs(val-e0)<=ep)
endfunction
```

For b) the criterion is to stop when the difference is very small.
In c) the comparison of the results goes very well to the approximations. In d)I think it is not necessary because my code calculates for values of x <0, and therefore in e) I don't know what to do either.
I don't know what I did wrong in my code, because I understand the purpose of the problem, which is to show the weakness of the floating point arithmetic, since at a certain point there are going to be cancellations, so I don't know what the problem of my implementation is.

I would appreciate any help in advance, regards.

Edit: for $x<0$

```
if x<0
  do
  aux1=pos;
  pos+=(x)^(2*n)/factorial(2*n);
  n++;
  until(abs(pos-aux1)<=ep)
  do
  aux2=neg;
  neg+=(x)^(2*m+1)/factorial(2*m+1);
  m++;
  until(abs(neg-aux2)<=ep)
  val=pos+neg;
else
```

Comment: For $x=-20$ your code produces a negative value. This approximation is way off. So your conclusion for c that it goes well is false.

Comment: Uhm, no, I have verified it and no, although I see that if there is an error and that it increases as x is a very large negative, but this also happens for very large positive x and it seems to me that it is because of the criteria that I am using . I have asked my teacher and he told me that the problem was that I do not do the sum when x is negative, that I do not do the evaluation, but according to me in the do it is done ...

Comment: On my computer for x = -20 it returns 0.00000020104

Comment: And well, for that last paragraph I planned to use the hint that is given in the previous paragraph, but they ask me to make a code that evaluates the sum, I have gotten a little confused or I do not know if I did not understand my teacher

Comment: All right so a difference in computer architecture yields that. What about for smaller values of x? x = -30,-40,...? The point of this problem is to show you that it does happen but I guess they didn't go large enough to consider other processors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For $x < 0$, As $x$ gets smaller, you would have a bunch of cancellation errors due to the alternating addition and subtraction. For $x > 0$ there is only addition so you avoid those.

A hint is given to you that $e^{-x} = \frac{1}{e^x}$

You can avoid cancellation errors for $e^{-x}$ by instead calculating $e^x$ and performing one final calculation $\frac{1}{e^x}$ when your tolerance is matched

Comment: Thank you very much for answering. Indeed, for the values that it indicates in the comment it fails fatally. As I mentioned, my first option to perform the addition was to use the property of the exponential that is mentioned, but my teacher asks me to solve it without using that gadget and I can't think of how that is possible

Comment: If $x < 0$, then all the odd powered terms are negative. An alternative you can do instead then to minimize cancellation errors is add up these negative terms separately and doing only 1 subtraction operation. ie (sum of even powers) + (sum of odd powers), and since the sum of the odd powers is negative it's a subtraction

Comment: Thanks a lot! That seems to work

Comment: Hello, I still have problems for the part of x <0, the implementation that I have made I have put it as edit in the post, but when I graph this compared to the initial one, where I do not put any conditions for x, and it turns out that with this condition for x <0 the error is much higher, I think I have a programming error, but I analyze it and analyze it and I can't see where my error is ...

Comment: Your error is that you're comparing the tolerance for positive and negative values separately. This tolerance checking should be done only after the two values have been added together.  You'll need to modify your code quite a bit to do this.